# How to change the color of the score plot in PLS analysis in the ropls package?

Tags: r, pls

How to change the color of the score plot in PLS analysis in the ropls package?

```
library(ropls)
data(sacurine)

sacurine.pls <- opls(x = sacurine$dataMatrix, y = sacurine$sampleMetadata[, 'bmi'], orthoI = 0)
plot(sacurine.pls,typeVc = "x-score",parPaletteVc = c("red","white","blue"))
```

Comment: Does `parPaletteVc = c("red","white","blue")` only work in OPLSDA and PLSDA analysis? It seems to have no effect in PLS and OPLS analysis.